# Unable to concatenate Char Datatype and string in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I came across this scenario wherein I tried to concatenate a Char data type variable and a string but the results were pretty surprising.

```
declare @Var char(10) = 546875.5
set @Var = @Var + '100' 
select @Var
```

Output: 546875.5

I tried to increase the size of the variable , but still the same result.

```
declare @Var char(100) = 546875.5
set @Var = @Var + '100' 
select @Var
```

Output : 546875.5

When I reversed the concatenation, strings did concatenate :

```
declare @Var char(10) = 546875.5
set @Var = '100' + @Var 
select @Var
```

Output: 100546875.

Can anyone please help me solve this mystery.

Please note:: I understand that I can convert both before concatenating and that will serve the purpose. But I am not sure why this is not working.

TIA !!

Comment: try using Select CONCAT(@Var,'100')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Var is right-padded with spaces because you used char instead of varchar. The spaces take up the entire available length, so there is nowhere for the '100' to be appended.

This can be seen with:

```
declare @Var char(100) = 546875.5 
set @Var = @Var + '100' 
select replace(@Var, ' ', 'X')
```

Change @Var to be varchar and you'll be fine. (And you need at least 11 characters).

```
declare @Var varchar(11) = 546875.5 
set @Var = @Var + '100' 
select @Var
```

Answer (score 2):

If you will use `char` data type, then you need to declare another `char` type variable and `set` `concat` value to that variable.

```
DECLARE @Var CHAR(10)='546875.5'
DECLARE @FinalVar CHAR(15)
SET @FinalVar=@Var + '100'
SELECT replace(@FinalVar,' ','')
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to Trim the leading and trailing spaces before concatenating

```
declare @Var CHAR(100) = 546875.5
SET @Var = LTRIM(RTRIM(@Var)) + '100' 
SELECT @Var
```

Result

[image]